# Missing regions in Firebase NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project in `asia-south1` (Mumbai).

I'm trying to set up a firestore trigger like this:

```js
firebaseFunctions.region('asia-south1').firestore.document('likes/{id}').onCreate(handleLikeCreation);
```

But as the `SUPPORTED_REGIONS` array in Firebase doesn't contain `asia-south1`, I'm getting this error:

```
!  Error: The only valid regions are: us-central1, us-east1, us-east4, europe-west1, europe-west2, as
ia-east2, asia-northeast1
    at assertRegionsAreValid (C:\Users\David\Dropbox\projects-active\socialape\socialape-functions\fu
nctions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\function-builder.js:62:15)
```

I'm stuck at this point. In Firebase, the region can be set only once (and I did) so I can't move my infrastructure, and recreating the whole thing is a hassle. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Also: I don't get why this region is not in the NPM package, as it's perfectly supported by the package, my infrastructure works, my app works, it's just missing from the array. If someone knows the reason, it'd be a relief to know the cause.

My NPM versions are:

```
    "firebase": "^6.3.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real "fix".  asia-south1 is simply currently not a supported region for Cloud Functions, [according to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations).  Pick another region that best meets your needs.

Comment: I wish Firebase gave some warning about this. It worked like a charm in this region all the way until I wanted to create triggers.